# Visual Studio Code - Dragging to highlight text moves way too fast at edges

Tags: visual-studio-code

is there a way to adjust the speed at which the code scrolls when highlighting using the cursor? If I need to highlight more code than I see in the normal view I will usually use my mouse to highlight from the top and move it down to the bottom.

In other text editors the code will scroll up and the highlighting continue at a reasonable pace.

In VS Code if you do this it will speed up incredibly fast, leading me to many times reach the end of the code. This is in the matter of pixels. Is there any way to adjust this speed?

Comment: I would report that as bug in the vscode Github repo. I'm pretty certain that there is no setting for this behavior.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: don't think so—I'm on nightly builds and it still is out of control!

Comment: here we are in 20220824 and this very bad vscode default setting is still here --- Arghh ... at least on Ubuntu vscode

Answer (score 9):

This is an active bug, [as reported here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40890). The quick fix is to add the following to your [user settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

`"editor.smoothScrolling": true`

Comment: As it is mentioned on that issue I don't think this is a fix.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit `settings.json` and add this line: `"editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 0.005`

> For me, that speed is just fine.

I also read that some have solved the problem with:

Go to File > Preferences > Settings. Search for: `mouseWheelScrollSensitivity`, change it for `0.01`

Try also to enable `smooth scrolling` as in the picture:

[image]

Comment: OP is asking for "dragging". `MouseWheel` setting is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Of course it matters. Dragging is not possible without what I wrote, that's why I gave such a comment, so it can be seen that it helped some people.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode 1.72 (Sept. 2022) should help, with [PR 161378](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/161378), as it does re-implement how dragging auto-scrolls is done in the editor.

This is done mainly in [`src/vs/editor/browser/controller/mouseHandler.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/83d7b8ecf760a39babd9c3fb20bd2a2854b3fedb/src/vs/editor/browser/controller/mouseHandler.ts), where new methods like [`TopBottomDragScrollingOperation #_getScrollSpeed()`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/83d7b8ecf760a39babd9c3fb20bd2a2854b3fedb/src/vs/editor/browser/controller/mouseHandler.ts#L668-L671) will help manage the selection dragging scroll speed.

You can test it out today, with [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).